# Why am I getting "Call to a member function getFloorplan() on a non-object"?

Tags: php, class, object

I have the following code in my php page:

```
  $fair           = Factory::new_fair_obj();
  $fairs          = $fair->getAllFairs();
  $fairs_ddl      = createFairDDL($fairs);
  $first_fair_id  = $fairs[0]['id'];
  $fair           = $fair->getFair($first_fair_id);  // <-- works till here
  $floorplan      = $fair->getFloorplan($first_fair_id);  // <-- This is where it breaks
```

And this is the business class which extends DAO:

```
interface iFair {
  public function getAllFairs();
  public function getFair($id);
  public function getFloorplan($id);
}

class Fair extends FairDAO implements iFair {
  protected $db;

  function __construct(&$db) {
    $this->db = $db;
  }
  public function getAllFairs(){
    return parent::getAllFairs();
  }

  public function getFair($id){
    return parent::getFair($id);
  }

  public function getFloorplan($id){
    return parent::getFloorplan($id);
  }
}
```

Calling `getFair()` works fine. But calling `getFloorplan()` on teh next line is not working.

How come?

Comment: What's the new value held by $fair after the following line? $fair           = $fair->getFair($first_fair_id);

Comment: Because getFair() doesn't return what you expect.

Answer (score 5):

Change the two lines to this:

```
$fair1           = $fair->getFair($first_fair_id);  // <-- works till here
$floorplan      = $fair->getFloorplan($first_fair_id);  // <-- This is where it breaks
```

you're getting the result of getFair() in the variable $fair which is same as an object's name. So it's just overriden.

Comment: you're getting the result of getFair() in the variable $fair which is same as an object's name. So it's just overriden.

Comment: Click the edit link below your post. You should add that comment to the bottom of your post. This way, there is no character limit and you can modify and better your answer.

Comment: Ah.... Thanks. I've been working for over 13 hours... so I'm kind of getting blind on my own code. Thanks :)

Comment: @Steve, yeah that happens to everyone, we can't find our own mistakes, because we don't think the way other ppl will. Cheers!